# How to properly inject fetched API response into a Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `google-map` with customized markers. Those markers are logos of companies. After inquiring the APIs I am able to obtain a `json` file with the vessels I am interested in.

**The problem** I have is that I have been trying to inject these vessels into a table on the user interface, without success unfortunately. How to do that?

[image: map]

Below the typical response from the [API](https://api.vesselfinder.com/docs/vesselslist.html)

```
[  
    {  
        "AIS":{  
            "MMSI":227441980,
            "TIMESTAMP":"2017-08-11 11:17:37 UTC",
            "LATITUDE":46.1459,
            "LONGITUDE":-1.16631,
            "COURSE":360.0,
            "SPEED":0.0,
            "HEADING":511,
            "NAVSTAT":1,            
            "IMO":0,
            "NAME":"CLEMENTINE",
            "CALLSIGN":"FJVK",
            "TYPE":60,
            "A":0,
            "B":0,
            "C":0,
            "D":0,
            "DRAUGHT":0.0,
            "DESTINATION":"",
            "ETA_AIS":"00-00 00:00",
            "ETA":"",
            "SRC":"TER",
            "ZONE": "North Sea",
            "ECA": true      
        }
    }
]
```

Below the code I am using to inject the value from the API fetch into the Table:

**ShipTracker.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';

const shipCompanyMap = {
    MICHIGAN: 'DONJON',
    ATLANTIC SALVOR': 'DONJON',
    STUYVESANT: 'DUTRA'
};

const Ship = ({ ship, logoMap, logoClick }) => {
const shipName = ship.AIS.NAME;
const company = shipCompanyMap[shipName];
const img = logoMap[company && company.split(' ').join('').toUpperCase()];
return (
    <div onClick={(event) => logoClick(event, ship)}>
        {/* Render shipImage image */}
        <img src={img} alt="Logo" />
    </div>
);
};
export { Ship };

const ShipTracker = ({ ships, setActiveShip }) => {
console.log('These are the ships: ', { ships });

return (
    <div className="ship-tracker">
        <Table className="flags-table" responsive hover>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>MMSI</th>
                    <th>TIMESTAMP</th>
                    <th>LATITUDE</th>
                    <th>LONGITUDE</th>
                    <th>COURSE</th>
                    <th>SPEED</th>
                    <th>HEADING</th>
                    <th>NAVSTAT</th>
                    <th>IMO</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>CALLSIGN</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {ships.map((ship, index) => {
                    // const { IMO, NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE } = ship;
                    // const cells = [ NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, IMO, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE ];

                    const {
                        MMSI,
                        TIMESTAMP,
                        LATITUDE,
                        LONGITUDE,
                        COURSE,
                        SPEED,
                        HEADING,
                        NAVSTAT,
                        IMO,
                        NAME,
                        CALLSIGN
                    } = ship;

                    const cells = [
                        MMSI,
                        TIMESTAMP,
                        LATITUDE,
                        LONGITUDE,
                        COURSE,
                        SPEED,
                        HEADING,
                        NAVSTAT,
                        IMO,
                        NAME,
                        CALLSIGN
                    ];

                    return (
                        <tr
                            onClick={() => setActiveShip(ship.AIS.NAME, ship.AIS.LATITUDE, ship.AIS.LONGITUDE)}
                            key={index}
                        >
                            <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                            {cells.map((cell) => <td key={ship.AIS.MMSI}>{cell}</td>)}
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    </div>
);
};

export default ShipTracker;
```

The file **GoogleMap.js** below is carrying `<ShipTracker />` information:

```
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: false,
            buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
            progress: 0,
            ships: [],
            type: 'All',
            shipTypes: [],
            activeShipTypes: [],
            logoMap: {}
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
        }, 500);

        await this.updateRequest();

        const shipTypeResults = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'comp'
        });
        const shipTypes = shipTypeResults.items.map((data) => data.fields);

        const logoMap = shipTypes.reduce((acc, type) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [type.name]: type.images.fields.file.url
            };
        }, {});
        this.setState({
            logoMap
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.type !== prevState.type) {
            console.log('dropdown value changed for ' + this.state.type);
        }
    }

    async updateRequest() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/hello';
        const fetchingData = await fetch(url);
        const ships = await fetchingData.json();

        this.setState({
            ships
        });
    }

    handleMarkerClick = (event, data) => {
        this.props.setActiveShip(data.AIS.NAME, data.AIS.LATITUDE, data.AIS.LONGITUDE);
    };

    render() {
        console.log('ships ', this.state.ships);
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'KEY' }}
                    center={{
                        lat: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.latitude : 37.99,
                        lng: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.longitude : -97.31
                    }}
                    zoom={5.5}
                >
                    {/* Rendering all the markers here */}
                    {this.state.ships.map((ship) => (
                        <Ship
                            ship={ship}
                            key={ship.AIS.MMSI}
                            lat={ship.AIS.LATITUDE}
                            lng={ship.AIS.LONGITUDE}
                            logoMap={this.state.logoMap}
                            logoClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
                        />
                    ))}
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default class GoogleMap extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: [],
        activeShipTypes: [],
        activeCompanies: [],
        activeShip: null
    };

    setActiveShip = (name, latitude, longitude) => {
        this.setState({
            activeShip: {
                name,
                latitude,
                longitude
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <MapContainer>

                <BoatMap
                    setActiveShip={this.setActiveShip}
                    activeShip={this.state.activeShip}
                    handleDropdownChange={this.handleDropdownChange}
                />
                <ShipTracker
                    ships={this.state.ships}
                    setActiveShip={this.setActiveShip}
                    onMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
                />
            </MapContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATES AFTER SUGGESTIONS:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <MapContainer>
            <BoatMap
                setActiveShip={this.setActiveShip}
                activeShip={this.state.activeShip}
                handleDropdownChange={this.handleDropdownChange}
                ships={this.state.ships} // <-- Added here
            />
            <ShipTracker
                ships={this.state.ships}
                setActiveShip={this.setActiveShip}
                onMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
            />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

I have been researching a lot and came across [this source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-json-data-to-a-html-table-using-javascript-jquery/) and [this other source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced) which were useful but didn't solve the problem.
Am I maybe misunderstanding the response of the API and how to inject the data?

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you deconstruct properties from `ship`, you need to get them from `ship.AIS` not simply `ship` because `ship.MMSI`, `ship.TIMESTAMP` etc will be undefined.

```
const {
 MMSI,
 TIMESTAMP,
 LATITUDE,
 LONGITUDE,
 COURSE,
 SPEED,
 HEADING,
 NAVSTAT,
 IMO,
 NAME,
 CALLSIGN
} = ship.AIS;
//  ^ correct
```

---

Second issue: `GoogleMap` has `ships` in its state but it never gets set to anything. The actual source of data is in `BoatMap`'s `state.ships`. Therefore you can pass that down from `BoatMap` to a prop to `GoogleMap` and remove the `state.ships` from `GoogleMap`.

In `BoatMap`, pass `ships` as a prop:

```
<GoogleMapReact
    ships={this.state.ships}
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'KEY' }}
    ...
    ...
```

In `GoogleMap`, use `this.props.ships` instead of `this.state.ships`:

```
<ShipTracker
    ships={this.props.ships}
```

After making those changes, if you're still having trouble, add a `console.log` here, to verify your fetch is working:

```
const ships = await fetchingData.json();
console.log('fetched ships', ships);
```

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. I tried that but it still does not work. Maybe there is something else that needs to be added?

Comment: Add some `console.log` after that line like `console.log(MMSI)`. Another for `console.log(cells)` etc etc.

Comment: That is strange, [here](https://i.imgur.com/oiGXCuF.png) I don't see anything in particular and [here](https://i.imgur.com/Ica4duh.png) too. Do you see something I don't see?

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/uuDWsPk.png) is the latest modification

Comment: There we can see `ShipTracker` is not receiving any ships at all, it receives an empty array. Show how you use `<ShipTracker />` and the source of its props.

Comment: Ok I added a snippet of the `GoogleMap.js` file where `<ShipTracker />` is used

Comment: Maybe the problem is where I set `setActiveShip`?

Comment: `GoogleMap` has state `ships: []` which never gets set to anything. Pass `ships` down from `BoatMap` to `GoogleMap` as a prop.

Comment: I see. Could you please add some code so that I can better understand your suggestion? That would be very helpful! :)

Comment: Do you mean at the `render()` in the `export default class GoogleMap extends React.Component {.....` but that already contains a `state.ships`.

Comment: I added **UPDATES** on the question with the modification I understood from your suggestion. But I am not sure if that is what you ment

Comment: Thank you for your time. I get [this error](https://i.imgur.com/E3quvfN.png) which I don't understand.

Comment: Did you try adding the `fetched ships` log in my answer? That will confirm that the actual fetch ships source is working before proceeding.